# Problems with atoi() exercise

Tags: c, loops, atoi

I'm having problems with this simple loop exercise.  I think the code is correct and I don't get any errors however when I run the program, I just get "^C" over and over again.  Please help.

```
#import <readline/readline.h>
#import <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Where should I start counting? ");
    const char *numInput = readline(NULL);
    int countDownStart = atoi(numInput);
    for (int i = countDownStart; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i % 3 == 0){
            printf("%d\n", i);
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                printf("Found one!\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

UPDATE 8/3/14

The code works when I enter the starting number using the numbers above my keyboard.  However when I enter the starting number with my 10 key, I get "^C" every time I hit enter.  Now I'm completely flummoxed but at least my code works.

Thank you for the help everyone.  I understand atoi is not the best function to use but am trying to work through the Big Nerd Objective-C book.

Comment: Does your program compile?  The #import directive is normally used for libraries on MS.  They should be #include.

Answer (score 0):

Use strtol inplace of atoi as it returns error value in case of conversion failures.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the output received from function readline

```
const char *numInput = readline(NULL);
printf ("Input %s", numInput); //debugging
int countDownStart = atoi(numInput);
```

If the function is always returning the same string means, then the result also will remain the same.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I will do that going forward.